# Please help how to undo 301 on blog?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I have a landing page on example.com and then a blog at example.com/blog.  I noticed I have very little traffic on the blog even though it has 45 posts. I went to Bing Webmaster Tools and found this 301 message "moved permanently" on H1 and title tags which I want to remove. My landing page looks perfect for title and H1 tags and the meta name on the landing page is perfect also. How can I get this on my blog too? Am I right in thinking this is why I have so little traffic?

Comment: What does 301 message "on H1 and title tags" mean? 301s are applied to entire URLs, not page elements.

Answer (score 1):

As your site is at the moment, it doesn't seem like there is any problem involving a 301 status.  If a user were to enter the URL `parenting4specialneeds.com/blog` then with a normal browser the user will end up viewing your "About Me" page, which is located at `parenting4specialneeds.com/blog/` (note the extra "/" at the end).  Internally the browser does actually receive a "301 moved permanently" response which tells it that the page should be retrieved from `parenting4specialneeds.com/blog/` but this is normal, and nothing to worry about.  The browser will automatically get the right page.

If I were you, I would rethink what you want for what you are calling your "landing page", the one at `parenting4specialneeds.com/`.  What you have now is a rudimentary page which forces any visitor to enter an email address to go anywhere or see anything (and it's pretty "spammy" looking, besides).  You'd quickly lose a lot of visitors right there, I'd think.  The page comes after that, for those who enter an email, is even more rudimentary, and does not have any link to your blog either.  So your blog will not be getting any views if anyone were to come to your "landing page".  The general quality of your blog pages seem much better than your landing page and its successor page.  Perhaps you should use a blog page as your landing page (with a redirect!).

Comment: thanks so much for that-I will make these changes-greatly appreciate your help and your honesty!